# copied 200 lines of excel table into a handsontable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have a hansontable with 30 lines on page load. I do a copy/paste of 200 lines of excel table into a javascript handsontable table, however when I try to count rows (tr's), it get 80 in Mozilla (and 78 in IE???). Even less is Mozilla debug (F12) Am I doing something wrong?

```
    $('#btnShowMarkers').on('click', function(evt) {
         var count = 0;
         $("#example tr").each(function() {
            count++             
         });             
         alert(count);
    });
```

plugin options look like this...

```
    $('#example').handsontable({
        data: data,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        maxRows : 999,
        colHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true
    });
```

ref:
http://handsontable.com/

Comment: sidenote: don't use `alert`, it locks the entire page thread. Use `console.log` instead.

Comment: thank you, but this this is just for illustrative purposed, not production.

Comment: same comment still holds.

Comment: Thank you for valuable response.  We should obviously petition ECMA to ban such a repugnant function.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their examples, they seem to use special **.handsontable('getData');** method.
This seems to work better now...

```
<script src="../jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script src="../handsontable/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="../handsontable/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css">

<script type="text/javascript">             
  $( document ).ready(function() {

        var data = [
        ["", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes", "Mini", "Mitsubishi"],
        ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
        ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
        ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
        ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151]
        ];

        $('#example').handsontable({
            data: data,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            maxRows : 999,
            colHeaders: true,
            contextMenu: true
        });

        $('#btnShowMarkers').on('click', function() {           
            var myTableData = $('#example').handsontable('getData');        
            var count = 0;  
            $.each( myTableData, function( index, myRow ) {
                count = count + 1;
                $('#output').append("row " +  index +  " >> " );

                $.each( myRow, function( index, myCell ) { 
                    $('#output').append(myCell + " - "); 
                });

                $('#output').append("<br/>");
            }); 
            alert(count + " rows");
        });  // end click

  });  // end query

</script>
</head>

<div class="handsontable" id="example"></div><br/>
<button id='btnShowMarkers'>DUMP DATA</button>
<div id='output'></div>
```